# How to overload operator <<

Tags: c++, windows, qt, operators, operator-overloading

I try to overload `operator <<` in Qt.

```
class MyCryptographicHash : public QCryptographicHash
{
public:
    MyCryptographicHash(Algorithm method);

    void addData(const QString &data );

    friend MyCryptographicHash& operator<< (MyCryptographicHash &obj, const QString &value);

private:
    QByteArray _data;
};

MyCryptographicHash& operator<<(MyCryptographicHash &obj, const QString &value) {
    obj.addData(value);
    return obj;
}


    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    MyCryptographicHash *hash1 = new MyCryptographicHash(QCryptographicHash::Sha1);
    MyCryptographicHash *hash2 = new MyCryptographicHash(QCryptographicHash::Sha1);
    hash1->addData("abc1234");
    QString a;
    a = "qweer321";
    hash2<<a;
    qDebug() << "HASH1: " << hash1->result();
    qDebug() << "HASH2: " << hash2->result();
}
```

But I get error:

```
no match for 'operator<<' in 'hash2 << a'
```

I tried to declare the operator as a member of the class, but also get an error.

```
error: 'MyCryptographicHash& MyCryptographicHash::operator<<(MyCryptographicHash&, const QString&)' must take exactly one argument
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks alot!I'm a newbie :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code should be

```
*hash2 << a;
```

hash2 is a pointer, not an object.

However in the code you posted there is no obvious reason *why* hash2 is a pointer. So you could just write

```
{
    MyCryptographicHash hash1(QCryptographicHash::Sha1);
    MyCryptographicHash hash2(QCryptographicHash::Sha1);
    hash1.addData("abc1234");
    QString a;
    a = "qweer321";
    hash2 << a;
    qDebug() << "HASH1: " << hash1.result();
    qDebug() << "HASH2: " << hash2.result();
}
```

which would also have the advantage of not leaking memory.

But maybe there's more to this than the code you posted.